# How to add new array data to NSDictionary in plist file using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, plist

I have a plist file ("myAwayList.plist") to store navigation data. I have nested a Dictionary of String variables in an Array in the main Dictionary as follows..

```
<dict>
<key>Locations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Sydney City Centre</string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>Centrepoint Tower</string>
        <key>Lat</key>
        <string>-33.870451</string>
        <key>Lon</key>
        <string>151.208771</string>
    </dict> ...
```

I can successfully load and use the array data inside with the following...

```
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0)as NSString
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myAwayList.plist")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    // Check if file exists
    if(!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path))
    {
        // If it doesn't, copy it from the default file in the Resources folder
        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myAwayList", ofType: "plist")
        fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle!, toPath: path, error:nil)
        println("File did not exist! Default copied...")
    }
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)!
    let mySavedLocations: AnyObject = dict.objectForKey("Locations")!
    println("plist all: \(mySavedLocations)")
    if let nsArray:NSArray = mySavedLocations as? NSArray{
        for var loadCount = 0; loadCount < mySavedLocations.count; ++loadCount {
            var locationDict:AnyObject = nsArray[loadCount] // loading array data at index
            let arrayName = locationDict["Name"] as AnyObject? as String
            let arrayAddress = locationDict["Address"] as AnyObject? as String
            let arrayLat = locationDict["Lat"] as AnyObject? as String
            let arrayLon = locationDict["Lon"] as AnyObject? as String
            awaydatalist.append(AwayData(name:arrayName, address:arrayAddress, lat:arrayLat, lon:arrayLon))   // This is a list array used to display the loaded data on a ViewController
        }
    }
```

I now want to append the array inside with another row of data, and write back to the plist file, but I cannot find a way to do it. Please advise?
Chris

Comment: You want to add new dictionary inside array and update the data in plist.Right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to add new Dictionary inside the array stored in plist file

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0)as NSString
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myAwayList.plist")


    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    // Check if file exists
    if(!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path))
    {
        // If it doesn't, copy it from the default file in the Resources folder
        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myAwayList", ofType: "plist")
        fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle!, toPath: path, error:nil)
        println("File did not exist! Default copied...")
    }

    let dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)!

    let mySavedLocations: AnyObject = dict.objectForKey("Locations")!

    println("plist all: \(mySavedLocations)")

    if let nsArray:NSArray = mySavedLocations as? NSArray
    {
        for var loadCount = 0; loadCount < mySavedLocations.count; ++loadCount
        {
            var locationDict:AnyObject = nsArray[loadCount] // loading array data at index
            let arrayName = locationDict["Name"] as AnyObject? as String
            let arrayAddress = locationDict["Address"] as AnyObject? as String
            let arrayLat = locationDict["Lat"] as AnyObject? as String
            let arrayLon = locationDict["Lon"] as AnyObject? as String
          //  awaydatalist.append(AwayData(name:arrayName, address:arrayAddress, lat:arrayLat, lon:arrayLon))   // This is a list array used to display the loaded data on a ViewController
        }
    }

    //Convert AnyObject to NSMutableArray
    var twDataArray = (mySavedLocations as NSMutableArray) as NSMutableArray

    //Create a new Dictionary
    let airports: [String: String] = ["Name": "Toronto Pearson", "Address": "Dublin","Lat":"23.23","Lon":"78.89"]

    //add dictionary to array
    twDataArray.addObject(airports)

    //set the new array for location key
    dict.setObject(mySavedLocations, forKey: "Locations")

    //update the plist
    dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

This code add a new dictionary inside the location array.

Comment: Thanks, I can follow your code, but it crashes at the line... twDataArray.addObject(airports); with the error "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" ???

Comment: .. even without the semi-colon ";"   ... still crashes ;-)

Comment: I add this code in viewDidLoad() method and its work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you very much Nimisha, I needed to define my dictionary as Mutable for it to work (as you did). Works perfectly, Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisKing If you accept the answer, it will helpful for other users to find out the right answer.